Amcharts5 grouping strategy
I'm using Amcharts 5 with angular, XYChart with LineSeries with DateAxis on x axis.
i have activated data grouping by setting groupData: true. The default amcharts5 grouping strategy is "Last" , this means it take the last data for grouping. I want to change this to "High" to take the max value of data when grouping.
How I can do it please ?
I have tryed to use groupDataCallback call  back instead , but not working as expected. when i zooming at the max level the point still grouped , causing the points apearing and desapearing each time add point to graph
thank you

You can use LineSeries setting valueYGrouped to set which aggregate value to use. In your case, it's "high", e.g.:
var series = chart.series.push(
  am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    valueXField: "date",
    valueYField: "value",
    valueYGrouped: "high"
  })
);

All possible values are "open", "close", "low", "high", "average", "sum", "extreme".
For more information about this, visit official DateAxis tutorial.
